# UX failures on UX

Tags: discussion, design, mockups, usability, ux

I just consider that the UX site has UX failures:

- The UI wireframe icon is similar to the image icon. Sometimes I want to post an image and I click the wireframe icon
- The wireframe dialog has an icon with an "X" at its top right corner. Anybody used to Windows OS, and that is more than 90% of people who uses computers, will think it is a close button instead of an "Hide Markup" toggle. I suggest changing it to to be a press button, its contents to be "<>" and putting it on another location. 
   Even if you do this, there is another problem, the full screen icon, due to its shape and location, is also very similar to a close button!
- The UX website has not a link to the respective meta site; and it is an observation valid for every StackExchange subsite.

Comment: Many of these are down to the Balsamiq mockup tool itself, rather than Stack Exchange (It is not built by Stack Exchange). But yes, things could always be improved.